# ERC721 Token Transfer Outside Smart Contract

Tags: openzeppelin-contracts, nft

I am using OpenZeppelin ERC721 implementation for my non fungible tokens. Basically I have a smart contract which inherits from the OZ ERC721.sol. I am just wondering is the tokens only transferable between addresses through the smart contract functions such as safeTransferFrom (and other relevant functions)? For example, could I transfer the NFT through an external provider like in the Metamask UI?

Comment: Metamask just invokes the contract functions.

Comment: To transfer your NFT with Metamask, just import the contract address into the web extension.